# How to define type of 3 users(Teacher, Parent, Student) and login them

Tags: django, django-models, django-views

I am gonna create an electronic_diary for school. How to define type of 3 users(Teacher, Parent, Student) and login them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your question is very generic, so here is a generic answer, it will help you get started:

there are two solutions:

- create a user profile model and connect it to existing django user model, add user_type field there [doc](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/auth/customizing/#extending-user)
- create your own user model for django and add user_type field there [doc](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/auth/customizing/#auth-custom-user)

then on login and queries get user_type and change query/forms/permissions based on that

read the whole doc on [this](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/auth/customizing) page it's good!

Comment: I think it's personal opinion and also related your project ecosystem, check [link1](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29573138/django-extending-user-model-vs-creating-user-profile-model) and [link2](https://www.reddit.com/r/django/comments/3rerlk/is_it_better_to_use_own_user_profile_or_djangos/) it might be helpfull

Comment: note that if it's an existing project and it's already in production (there are some important stuff in tables) I prefer using profile model (creating a custom user model might be a little hard for this kind of project)